# Where is it first mentioned that the Jews partook in the feast of Achashverosh?

Tags: sources-mekorot, purim, tractate-megillah

In a discussion in the [Gemara Megillah 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.12a.9?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en#:%7E:text=If%20so%2C%20those%20in%20Shushan%20should%20have%20been%20killed), it is mentioned in the name of Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai that the Jews participated in the feast of Achashverosh.

Is there an earlier mention of this?

(I am aware of the numerous sources that mention that they attended, i am looking for the earliest mention of it)

Comment: There the point is that it says the Jews were deserving of punishment due to benefiting from the feast, but assuming there were Jews living  in Shushan, isn't it already implied in the pshat in the Megilla that they attended the feast "ובמלואת הימים האלה עשה המלך לכל העם הנמצאים בשושן הבירה למגדול ועד קטן משתה שבעת ימים"?  In the Targum on Esther it says that Mordechai and his small group of followers were the exception who did not join, and this is not implied directly in the pasuk.

Comment: There were Jews living in Shushan. See 2:5. If that does not suffice, @TheTargum, do you want something earlier than Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai, or the gemara Megilla?

Comment: There are Midrashim that also say this, although it's the students of Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai who say it not him (the opinions are reversed from the gemarra). Is that earlier for you or you want an earlier Sage.

Comment: @RabbiKaii , yes please, if there are earlier or similar time period mentions of jews partaking in the feast,  i would definitely appreciate hearing them